# How to compare products data from different store

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I have two store in my magento site, I want to get product_ids for which price is not matched for both stores.

For Example:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','price'));

foreach($collection as $val)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId('1')->load($val->getEntityId());
    if($val->getPrice() != $product->getPrice())
    {
        // here I can get product_ids for which price are different for both stores
    }
}
```

The above script is working and returning product_ids as my requirement, but I have more than 35000 products in my site and this script takes time to execute or sometime it gives timeout error.

Is there any other method using magento or php functions so that I can get those product_ids in an array?

Answer (score 0):

**Set `Flat Catalog Product`** [Reffer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25813/45103)

Then try below code (**Not Tested**)

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');//Collection from current store
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('storeOne'=> 'catalog_product_flat_1'),'main_table.price!=storeOne.price',array('*'));

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($collection);
```

**For more [Detail](http://inchoo.net/magento/flat-tables-in-magento-and-product-collection/)**